# MSBuild server with a solution containing .Net 4 and 4.5 projects not compiling correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

We have a solution that contains 50+ projects which are all in .NET 4.0, with the main program in a WPF project.  We have MSBuild set up to compile on check-in and this all works as it should.  We are now looking to migrate the WPF project to MVC 5 and have added an MVC project to our solution that targets .NET 4.5.1.  This all compiles and runs fine on our local machines but the build server errors with lots of "The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" errors.

After some investigation it looks like the build server is trying to compile the MVC project as .NET 4 instead of 4.5, is there a way to make the build server compile this project as 4.5 and the rest as 4.0 like Visual Studio does?  The other projects must stay as 4.0 for the time being so we can't upgrade them yet.  The build server has .NET 4.5 installed and the MSBuild arguments has "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0".

Comment: Does the build server have .net 4.5.1? Because your post suggests that you use .net 4.5 there but .net 4.5.1 in the project. Also, do you have nuget installed and internet connectivity to nuget.org on your build server?

Comment: yes it has .NET 4.5.1 installed along with VS2013 and internet connectivity

Comment: I guess now you need to set the logging to diagnostic and then look at it...